# How to generate g and p for DH safely on Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino, cryptography, diffie-hellman, public-key-exchange

I want to make a DH Key exchange with a PC and an Arduino. I want to generate a Prime p and a Base g on the Arduino that should be 2048 Bits long.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You shoud give some example, what have you tried yet and what is your specific problem.

Comment: I tried to use the crypto library for Arduino, but when I took both outputs I got different keys, so I want to do my own key exchange. It should talk from the Arduino to a chrome extention over a python bridge(I already did the python bridge)

Answer (score 0):

You don't generate `p` and `g`.

They are specified by the Diffie-Hellman group choice.

You only need to generate a random integer in the range of zero to the group mod-1.